# Flutter ios - Multiple commands produce 'xxx/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-ios

I'm on Mac M1. I've been creating flavors for my flutter app (involved some work in xcode). Now when I try to run ios I get:

> Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both
> /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x220357678) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
> (0x1066202c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
>
> Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce
> '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app':
>
> 1. Target 'Runner' has link command with output
>    '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app'
> 2. Target 'Runner' has create directory command with output
>    '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app'
>
> Encountered error while building for device.

I've been trying all sorts of things to fix this little error and probably breaking my app.

Here is a bunch of settings that seem relevant:

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]
Full error:

> benjaminfarquhar@MacBook-Pro vepo_front_end % flutter build ios
> --debug Building com.benjaminfarquhar.vepo for device (ios)... Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified
> development team in Xcode project: 5256E329AM Running pod install...
> 2,579ms Running Xcode build...
> Xcode build done.                                            3.2s
> Failed to build iOS app Error output from Xcode build: ↳
> objc[34678]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x220357678) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
> (0x1066202c8). One of
> the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> objc[34678]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libamsupport.dylib (0x2203576c8) and
> /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
> (0x106620318). One of
> the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> 2022-03-12 10:20:29.519 xcodebuild[34678:4448705] warning:  The file reference for "Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig" is a
> member of multiple groups ("Pods-Runner" and "Pods-Runner"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership
> in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the
> same file in more than one group, please add another reference to the same path.
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
> Writing result bundle at path:
> /var/folders/37/zgg8z2yj5sq03glqv_2sygn80000gn/T/flutter_tools.0ZIxKq/flutter_ios_build_temp_diryRJHxB/temporary_xcres
> ult_bundle
>
> ```
> note: Using new build system
> note: Planning
> note: Build preparation complete
> note: Building targets in dependency order
> error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app':
> 1) Target 'Runner' has link command with output
> '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app'
> 2) Target 'Runner' has create directory command with output
> '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app'
>
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> ```
>
> warning: The iOS deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99.
> (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99.
> (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99.
> (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
> warning: duplicate output file '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app'
> on task:
> MkDir /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app
> (in target 'Runner' from project
> 'Runner')
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj:
> warning: The iOS deployment target
> 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99.
> (in target 'ReachabilitySwift' from project 'Pods')
>
> ```
> Result bundle written to path:
>     /var/folders/37/zgg8z2yj5sq03glqv_2sygn80000gn/T/flutter_tools.0ZIxKq/flutter_ios_build_temp_diryRJHxB/temporary_xcres
>     ult_bundle
> ```
>
> Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce
> '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app':
>
> 1. Target 'Runner' has link command with output
>    '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app'
> 2. Target 'Runner' has create directory command with output
>    '/Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_front_end/build/ios/debug-iphoneos/.app'
>
> Encountered error while building for device.

**UPDATE:** [These answers do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936334/flutter-ios-error-class-amsupporturlconnectiondelegate-is-implemented-in-both-u). I don't think they worked for the OP either since they didn't mark an answer as the solution.

I think I might need Debug.xcconfig and Release.xcconfig inside the Flutter folder but when I select them in xcode they don't display any contents:

[image]

Comment: could you please give a reproducible sample (possibly in github)

Answer (score 0):

run `arch -x86_64 pod install` command on the terminal with project path

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.